# Emulator always crashes with error "Error While waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD has terminated"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm now stuck assuming its hardware, but wouldn't make too much sense as it used to work before, and just stopped out of nowhere.

Yesterday the whole day, when trying to open emulator on any device, in any api, in any app (including opening just the emulator by itself), I get This crash message.

I've tried uninstalling and installing android studio, and didn't work. I ended up fully formatting my pc, and installing AS again. The error persisted in the first 3 runs, and after creating a device running api 28, it shows This error (that I have had before). When I used to see it, I would still be able to run the app, but now it was just a black screen.

I found out that even though I installed the latest recommended version of AS, it didn't come with abd.exe. I downloaded the plstform-tools.zip, and when adding everything inside my sdk folder, avd stopped working. I decided to only add instead, the abd.exe file. Avd opened again, but the screen still stayed black.

I'm running amd Radeon 7500, so I decided to try an emulator running ARM64. The emulator just loads forever, but never opens up.

Right now, when I try to run api 29 or 30, instead of getting the same crash message as usual, I will just get a pop up saying the emulator was terminated, and shows in console log "error while waiting for the device: emulator proccess for avd was killed"

To add: for some random reason, all my installations today and yesterday, did not include an uninstall.exe

I tried opening emulator using CMD, and the error I get is

"cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed"

I have seen this error online, but seems like it usually shows an extra line saying "Emulator terminated with exit code" Mine does not have that.

I also have tried using Emulated performance in Software mode

Comment: Please post your solution as answer and accept it later to mark your problem solved. this is how SO works

Answer (score 1):

Someone at Reddit was able to help me:

for anyone that gets stuck here in the future, try this:

open c:\Users(user name).Android and create a file called “advancedFeatures.ini”. In this file, write:

Vulkan = off

GLDirectMem = on

Comment: Thanks. This just worked for me on someone's computer with, presumably, an AMD graphics card. This issue really should be resolved with a driver update but this is a great trick to know when doing those updates is not an option.