# Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio with everything up to date.

I can find information about "the emulator was killed", but I have a different error message:

[image: Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD has terminated]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulator always crashes with error "Error While waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD has terminated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68640302/emulator-always-crashes-with-error-error-while-waiting-for-device-the-emulator)

Comment: Kindly try opening the AVD using cmd. In cmd it might show errors that are stopping the AVD from running and hence terminating the AVD. Android Studio doesn't show errors when AVD is terminated, it just says that it is terminated. In cmd all the errors come like a file is corrupt etc.